# What's the influence of site migration on SEO?

Tags: wordpress, joomla, seo, migration

I have a site in WordPress (not designed by me!) and I want to re-design it myself using Joomla. The site already has a good rank in Google, I want to know what's the influence of this migration from WordPress to Joomla on my rank and SEO and what should I do to keep it as good as now?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple on page and off page factors that are going to impact your search engine ranking. What you will need to do is:

1/ Keep the same URL Structure. A good way will be create an XML Sitemap so you can track the URL of all the pages and posts. A big factor in SEO is "Page Rank" and keeping your urls the same will save the Page rank

2/ Keep the same content. Remember that Content is the key. If you change your content then the ranking will be most likely changed.

3/ If you use a SEO plugin on Wordpress (Like Yoast), Note down the Titles, Descriptions, Key phrases, Alt text, Anchor texts so you can do the same in the new site. Also make sure that you follow the SEO practice on the new site.

4/ Integrate youor new site in Google Web master tools and indicate any temporary redirects to Google.

Answer (score 1):

I recently moved my ecommerce site from interspire to wordpress. The way things panned out it was done adhoc.

Generally I would

- register a new name ( which I did ) so that you can keep your existing site as is until you have transferred all the content to the new site. If this is not an option find a way of developing the new site offline and having it all completely set up first.
- set up all your redirects from the old pages to the new ones before you move to the new site so that the search engines will very quickly find all the old pages and content.
- create a mailing list so that you can email everyone who has bought from you in the past, or subscribed to your site

Because my change over was a bit erratic my traffic and sales dropped quite considerable although it is now on the rise and I'm happy with my new site.
I'd also say that during the last 12 to 24 months the search engines have increasingly moved to a paid for placement model to monetise their businesses, so the drop is also down to this factor.